# Properly encapsulate array collection

Tags: ruby, oop, design-patterns, encapsulation

Hi I was tasked with building an app with the following brief.

Implement an interface, which calculates prices based on promotional rules.

```
co = Checkout.new(promotional_rules)
co.scan(item)
co.scan(item)
price = co.total
```

Essentially, depending on the promotional rules set up, certain items are discounted accordingly.

I had some feedback on my code stating that I have encapsulated the group of promotional_rules and then exposed the rules as an array anyway - bad OO

I initially created a promotional_rules object, which contains an array of rules.

```
  def initialize
    @rules = []
  end

 def addrule(rule)
   @rules.push(rule)
 end
```

Then in my checkout object I have the promotional_rules object that has been setup and passed into the initializer. I loop through the array of rules contained in the promotional_rules object and apply them to the items scanned by the checkout object.

```
def initialize(promotionalrules=Promotionalrules.new)
  @promotionalrules = promotionalrules
end

....Other code

for rule in @promotionalrules.getrules
  for item in @items
    ##Execute rule on current item.
  end
end
```

Im not overly happy with my code...the loop with the loop etc. But am just looking for some help with encapsulation as Im not sure where I have gone wrong.

Any suggestions on good design patterns to apply to the brief would be beneficial also, as not too confident about the approach I took. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that they're complaining about this "exposure":

```
for rule in @promotionalrules.getrules
```

that bleeds the internal rules from your Promotionalrules (which probably should be called PromotionalRules) out to the caller. The fix is to reverse your logic a little bit:

```
class Promotionalrules
  #...
  # and possibly remove the getrules method completely
  def apply_to_item(item)
    # Apply @rules to item
  end
  #...
end
```

and then later:

```
# I'm not sure how the rules and item interact so this "each" might
# be a different iterator in reality
@items.each { |i| @promotional_rules.apply_to_item(i) }
```

The essential change is that you apply the ruleset as a whole to each item. This hides the ruleset implementation details and, as an extra bonus, allows you to easily support rules that depend on each other ("you can get discount X unless you're using coupon Y" and things like that).

Comment: Thats great, can see what they meant now. Am just thinking about the way my rules and items interact, and if that could be improved, but maybe thats another question. Anyway, at the moment, i loop through the array of rule objects in the PromotionalRules object, and apply them accordingly to each item

Comment: @namtax: Depending on the rules, it might even be better to hand the whole list of items to the ruleset and let the ruleset loop through the items, that would make it easier to handle "2 for the price of 1" and things like that.

Comment: True. Though that would involve a nested loop, as would be looping through rules, then looping through items within that loop.